# What to do when I cannot move or attack because of occupied tiles? (Softlocking bug?)

Tags: civilization-6

[image]

My archer and warrior is in the city. I have not yet discovered ship building. It seems like the game is soft locked. Is there anything I can do here? I cannot attack nor move with any of the units.

Comment: Can you not disband the warrior?

Comment: @RavenDreamer Sure, it's an option I guess. But not a very preferable one.

Comment: The archer should be able to fire at an enemy - in fact, the shoot icon seems clear. Is it possible you promoted the warrior recently? Because promotion uses up its movement for the turn.

Comment: @Shadur-don't-feed-the-AI I was not able to shoot and the warrior had moves left.